# Intersection of schubert varieties

Tags: partitions, intersection-theory, grassmannians, schubert-calculus, schubert-varieties

Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ $\in$ $\mathbb{P}^4$ be two planes that intersect in exactly one point $Q$. Let $P_1 \in L_1$, $P_2 \in L_2$ points, such that $P_1 \neq Q \neq P_2$. Using the duality theorem, show that there is exactly one plane in $\mathbb{P}^4$ that goes through $P_1$ and $P_2$ and intersects $L_1$ and $L_2$ in a line.
Determine this plane.

The duality theorem states the following:
Let $F^1, F^2$ be two transversal flags, and let $\lambda, \mu$ be two acceptable partitions with respect to $G(d, n)$, such that $|\lambda|+ |\mu| = (n-d) \cdot d$.
Then:
(1) If $\lambda, \mu$ are complementary, then $\Omega (F^1, \lambda) \cap \Omega( F^2, \mu)= 1$ point.
(2) Otherwise, $\Omega( F^1, \lambda) \cap \Omega( F^2, \mu)= \emptyset$.

The way I wanted to solve this problem was by finding all Schubert classes of G(3,5). There are 9 acceptable partitions (inclusive the zero partition), and calculating their intersection  after choosing the right Schubert classes.

However, in order to choose the right Schubert classes, I need to be able to interpret them geometrically, and that is where I am stuck at.

I would appreciate your help a lot.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Your wording sounds like a homework exercise.  Is this a homework exercises?  MathOverflow is not supposed to be used to solve homework exercises.  At any rate, you do not need any theorem to see that there is precisely one $2$-plane containing three noncollinear points $Q$, $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: More like a voluntary homework. I am not very familiar with this forum but I wss hoping I could get some useful hint that could help me solve this excersise.